Please merge [tag:antidebugging] into [tag:anti-debug]
As the title says: Please merge antidebugging into anti-debug.
AFAIK there can be aliases to tags, so it would make sense to get rid of the questionable (spelling-wise) antidebugging and keep anti-debug (or even call it anti-debugging if someone wants to be really nitpicky).

Sounds good to me. [tag:anti-debugging] Done.

I think both should be merged into anti-debugging 

personally I'd also prefer [tag:anti-debugging] as opposed to the existing two.
